# How to avoid wide characters in LWP::UserAgent?

Tags: perl

I am trying to download contents (formulas) of a web page in Perl. I have used "LWP::UserAgent" module to parse the content and taken care to check for UTF8 format. The code is as follows:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
my $response = $ua->get('http://www.abc.org/patent/formulae');

my $content =$response->decoded_content();

if (utf8::is_utf8($content))
{
    binmode STDOUT,':utf8';
}
else
{
    binmode STDOUT,':raw';
}

print $content;
```

But I still get wide characters & the output is as follows:

"Formula = &#10;             &#10;                &#10;                   Ï&#10;               &#10;                &#10;                   Ì&#10;               &#10;            &#10;             â¡&#10;             &#10;                (&#10;                &#10;                   &#10;                      c&#10;                  &#10;                   &#10;                      +&#10;                  &#10;               &#10;                /&#10;                &#10;                   &#10;                      c&#10;                  &#10;                   &#10;                      0&#10;                  &#10;               &#10;                )&#10;            &#10;             â&#10;             1&#10;          "

Whereas I want:

```
"Fromula = Ï Ì â¡ ( c + / c 0 ) â 1 "
```

How can we avoid that?

Comment: convert it before printing?

Answer (score 3):

The `decoded_content` uses encoding and charset information available in the HTTP header to decode your data. However, HTML files may specify a different encoding.

If you want your output file to be utf8, you should always apply the `:utf8` layer. What you are trying to do with `is_uft8` is *wrong*.

Perl strings are *internally* stored with two different encodings. This is absolutely irrelevant to you, the programmer. The `is_utf8` just reads the value of an internal flag that determines this internal representation. Just because this flag isn't set doesn't mean that one codepoint in your string may not be encoded as multiple bytes when encoded as `utf8`.

The data you fetch from the server has various levels of encodings

- encodings like compression
- charsets
- the charset specified by the HTML
- HTML entities like `&quot`.

The `decoded_content` takes care of the first two levels, the rest is left for you. To remove entities, you can use the [`HTML::Entities`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aEntities) module. Duh.

```
use open qw/:std :utf8/;  # Apply :utf8 layer to STD{IN,OUT,ERR}

...;

if ($response->is_success) {
  my $content = $response->decoded_content;
  print decode_entities $content;
}
```

Note that I cannot verify that this works; the URL you gave 404s (irritatingly, without sending the 404 status code).